# Problems with Ampersand start as “Run as administrator”

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wonder how do I run a .bat or .cmd file as an **administrator** within a folder where the name contains the same Ampersand "&"? every time I try to run the file appears an error ... at what I did when I try to run as administrator cmd understand that & the folder name is a command.

Let me illustrate, I have a folder called Projects in **Cmd & vbs** and a file called **Project 01.bat** when I try to run it as administrator until an error occurs q I remove it from the folder that contains the **"&"**
if the **Cmd & vbs**.

```
Folder name: Cmd & Vbs
Script name: Project 01.bat
Form of execution: Option “Run as administered” in the context menu
Version of windows: 7
```

### Example Script:

```
@Echo Off
Title Remover - [WMP] Buy online music
Color 4f
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Directory.Audio\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\WMPShopMusic" /f>nul 2>&1
echo msgbox"Removed!",vbinformation> %temp%\Msg.vbs
start /wait %temp%\Msg.vbs>nul 2>&1
Del %temp%\Msg.vbs>nul 2>&1
Exit
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please updated your question with the exact command you are running and the exact error message. Remember: We can't see your screen.

Comment: Try posting a simple test case that doesn't use a `reg delete` command in it, but instead contains only the code needed to reproduce the problem, and tell exactly what is happening. Again: We can't see your screen.

Comment: Put a video demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to YouTube.

Comment: Could try the following test? create a folder named any q has an "&" after this place create a simple .bat file with only one echo and pause and then try the same as administrator... and this is the error I'm having.

Comment: I would not recommend that you use the `&` character in a directory name when using cmd.exe shell script (batch). This is because the `&` character has a special interpretation to cmd.exe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but writing the posts I realized the solution, put it in the original post! thank you for everything again.

Comment: I undid your last edit. It is not appropriate to edit your question to add an answer. If you'd like to post an answer, please do so as an actual answer in the space below with the heading **Your Answer**. It is acceptable here to answer your own question, but you need to do so in the proper manner. More info in [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this problem is in runas configuration and the correction is below:

**Browse the regedit to:**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runas\command
```

**Changes the value:**

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "%1" %*
```

**To:**

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C ""%1"" %*
```

Comment: I believe you could also use `runas /user:Domain\Account "explorer c:\my&test"` to start Explorer as Domain\User and open the folder named `My&Test`

Comment: Hello, the problem occurs when you run a file within a folder that has the & ... explaining better if you have a file inside the folder "Files & Folders" and open it and run a bat file within it as administrator it will display an error.

Answer (score 1):

Bill is correct, for DOS to work with the `&` character, you need to escape it using `^` an example might help:

> C:\Temp>cd my&test
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Temp>cd my`^`&test
>
> C:\Temp\my&test>